# How to build Java webhook for new Google actions builder

Tags: java, webhooks, actions-on-google, actions-builder

I created the java webhook in past for dialogflow where 1-1 mapping of intent used to be done. Now I am working with actions builder & not getting how to define and build the handlers using Java.

Before @ForIntent was used to map the intents with java methods. Now how should I map the methods with any scene or handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there isn't a client library or a SDK to use in order to implement a webhook in Java for the Actions Builder.

You have to implement this manually, exposing and endpoint able to receive POST requests with a `HandlerRequest` object as input param, as specified in this [json-schema](https://github.com/actions-on-google/assistant-conversation-schema)

Once created your webhook, to select the handler to use you have to check the value under `handler.name` field of the request and invoke the right handler. To avoid hardcoded if/switch you could use a strategy pattern and reflection/bean loading to invoke the specific handler, using the value achieved by the field `handler.name`.